# Convex Sets - Intersection

Tags: convex-analysis

[image: Question]

The question we had to complete was:
Choose two points in the set whose line segment joining them is not in the set. For the question that I have posted, why is my answer (-sqrt(3),2),(sqrt(3),2) Not correct?

Comment: Are either of the points in the set $T$? $(-\sqrt{3})^2=3$ so it's not strictly greater than $3$. and $2^2=4$ which is not less than $3$.

Answer (score 0):

No. If $(x,y) = ( \pm \sqrt{3},2)$, then $x^2=3$ and $y^2=4$, hence $(x,y) \notin T$.